# update values of sql table using the values from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table in sql server.

```
id    start    end     value    flag
 1      10     20.2    102       T
 2      22     11      133       T
 3      12.1   15      pending    F
 4      10     20.2    pending    F
 5      22     11      pending    F
```

as you can see, `start` and `end` is same for `row 1 and 4`, and `row 2 and 5`.
But value of`row with id 1 is 102, and that of 4 is pending`,

i want to write a query, which looks for another occurance of same `start` and `end` and then update the column `value` to the value of respective start and end,  if it is pending. else leave it

i.e
I want to update the value column of the rows with id 4 and 5, with values in row with id 1 and 2.(pending to the respective value)

final result i am looking for is this:

```
id    start    end     value    flag
 1      10     20.2    102       T
 2      22     11      133       T
 3      12.1   15      pending    F
 4      10     20.2    102       F
 5      22     11      133       F
```

Comment: I don't even understand the change you made to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for row with id 1, there is a particular value(102) for `start=10 and end=20.2` , as you can see, in row with id 4, the start and end are same as that of row 1, but the value is pending in row 4.  i want to update the pending to the value of row with id 1, since in both rows, `start and end are same`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like below

```
update t1
set t1.value=t2.value
from tbl t1 
join
tbl t2 on 
t1.start=t2.start and t1.end=t2.end and t2.value not like 'pending'
and t1.value like 'pending'
```

For you comment

> if i havd to update Flag column also then?

please try this version

```
update t1
set t1.value=t2.value,
t1.flag=t2.flag
from tbl t1 
join
tbl t2 on 
t1.start=t2.start and t1.end=t2.end and t2.value not like 'pending'
and t1.value like 'pending'
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers the first version of the question, which I understood.

```
update t
    set status = 'done'
    where status = 'pending' and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.start = t.start and t2.end = t.end and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

Actually, I assume you want at least one row to be `'done'` (your question is not clear.  If so, then add `t2.status = 'done'` to the subquery.

Or, in SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by start, end) as cnt
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set status = 'done'
    where status <> 'done' and cnt > 1;
```

In this case, you would use `sum(case when status = 'done' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by start, end) as cnt` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: sir, i edited my question, actually, status is changed to value, ie. it may contain any integer. Please check

Comment: @SRingne . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answer.  You invalidate answers and that can draw downvotes.

Comment: I was just editing the question sir, i'm very sorry, but while editing your answer came. This seem very complex query for me, i'm a beginner

Comment: @SRingne modify the Gordon query and put Value column in the place of 'Done'

Comment: @mohan111 ok sir, i will try, did you mean set value= select value.... ?

Answer (score 0):

Just I'm modifying Gordon Query as that's is the best answer you can get for the question

**Query 1** :

```
 update t
        set status =
```

**t.value >> Remove 'Done'**

```
 where status = 'pending' and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.start = t.start and t2.end = t.end and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

**Query 2** :

```
 with toupdate as (
          select t.*, count(*) over (partition by start, end) as cnt
          from t
         )
    update T
        set status =
```

T.Value **>> Remove 'Done'**

```
 From toupdate
        where status <> 'done' and cnt > 1;
```